# How to fetch Programming or Tech related video from Youtube Data API V3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch Programming and Tech related videos from the Youtube Data API v3.

For now, I am using this URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=10&key=API_KEY&videoCategoryId=28&regionCode=US`

As you can see the `videoCategoryId=28` is a `Science & Technology` category but it also fetches all the science and tech related videos which I don't want.

I want to have only programming and tech related videos.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: According to [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#videoCategoryId) documentation and https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=US&key=API_KEY, nothing more related to *programming and tech* than `Science & Technology` exists. Is there any place where you found *Programming and Tech* or is it a pure invention of your own ?

Comment: Hi @BenjaminLoison I think you misunderstood my question.
As i have said in my question, i am able to get the videos related to `Science & Technology` by using `28` video category ID. 
But i want to only get videos related to programming or tech in general, and there is no category exits for that.
So is there any solution where i can only get the programming related videos.

Comment: I have understood well your question. The problem is that you are trying to filter by a criterion that does not officially exist. Maybe you can get your way by using the `tags` obtained from `part=snippet` of [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). For example [rfscVS0vtbw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw) has interesting tags.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison could you please explain what do you mean by `tags`?
Is that which will come into result?
Something like this.

`tags: ['Dhar Mann', 'motivation', 'motivational video', 'inspirational video', 'self improvement', 'self help', 'self development', 'personal development', 'short film', 'inspirational', 'life lessons']`

Comment: Yes, I mean something as you sent. Videos: list returns [`video Resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#response)s which may contain [`tags`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.tags[]).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Yes the response does contain tags but can you imagine the tags that i had sent you in my last reply were from `Science & Technology` category lol.
Even if i filter the tags, wouldn't it be a really, really expensive query?

Comment: It was just an idea, I don't have any other, good luck.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison thank you for your suggestions and time.
I think for now i will have to ditch my idea and look for other solutions.

Comment: You could try looking for `Programming and Tech` keywords in captions otherwise.